# Transfering / Migrating an entire Catalog

Tags: catalog, migration, transfer

Ive been trying to transfer the entire catalog from one Magento server to another and I've been experiencing some significant problems.

I can get most of the catalog data across, but I always end up missing something like product swatches, product categories or a product's custom options. To get these across I then end up building my own scripts that queries Magento, writes the data to a CSV file of my own design, and then write another script that will add this data to the other server.

Ive been asking the other developers in house, and apparently this is how they do every migration. They spend ages building lots of custom scripts just to transfer the catalog across, and apparently the different Magento sites are so different they have to build entirely new scripts when they transfer the next site.

Is this a common experience for everybody?

I feel like there must be a better way. Does anybody know of a better way to transfer the entire catalog (not just the products, but everything) to another server? Can we not just copy across the entire SQL Database?

Comment: Cannot you do product export from dataflow management?

Comment: If you have done this yourself you would know that this does not export the entire catalog. It does not export categories. It does not export custom options. It does not export related products. I am sure there are several other things this dataflow management does not export. I want something I can use that will allow me to migrate the ENTIRE catalog, with everything included. Do you know anything that will allow me to do this?

Comment: If you want everything then just export your database and install in your new server.

Comment: the entire database, as in every single table? is it as simple as this? ive been told this wont work (but i am not yet convinced one way or the other), but if you can explain this as an answer and it works i will mark you as correct!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get everything from your old server in to your new server's database follow these steps.

**To backup your `mysql database` from `shell` run this code**

`mysqldump -u root -p -h localhost old_db_name > your_file_name.sql`

This will backup your entire database.

**Now to restore your database to your new server, go to new server's `ssh` and run this code:**

`mysql -u[USERNAME] -p[PASSWORD] new_db_name < your_file_name.sql`

Remember you will need to have access to `shell` to both of these database.

Good luck.

Comment: does this also handle images? would simply copying the media folder work?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, actually this needs to copy everthing from your old server to new server, all files and folders in same position.

Comment: what if there are different versions of magento?

Comment: It should still work, however you are likely to get any error, but that can be fixed easily if that happens.